# FileInfo path not wokring in asp.net core delpoyed in ubuntu machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filepath

I have an ASP.NET 5.0 application deployed on a linux machine, developing on windows.

My goal: read file on a network path (192.168.1.2/...) in c# when published on linux

My issues:
When i run my project on localhost (windows) in c# it works:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"\\192.168.1.2\...");
```

When i publish my project in linux machine, i have this problem:

> Could not find file '/home/connect/Public/arborweb/VS/\192.168.1.2...

Why it's pointing on local linux instead as network path?

I tried:
@"smb://192.168.1.2/..."
@"////192.168.1.2//..."
And so on...

Is there a way to point directly on ip address?

Comment: [Does this thread useful to you ?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/834952/unc-with-dotnet-core.html)